# Rails routing question: how to pass a hash property to a generated resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

say I have this on my routes.rb:

```
resources :accounts
```

which gives me, among other things:

```
new_account GET /account/new
```

I need to generate this (for example) "/account/new#test"

How do you pass the "#test" to `new_account_path()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
new_account_path(:anchor => "test")
#/account/new#test
```